# Is it possible to set an anchor point for a div in CSS?

Tags: css

I finally got this cool little twitter bird that displays the latest tweet in my feed.

My only problem is about the placement of the actual tweet. Since the amount of characters constantly changes in each tweet the box expands vertically (enlarges in height) and sometimes makes the image look off/ruins the effect.

I'm still not great at CSS so I'm not sure if I'm missing something simple, but here are two examples to illustrate this concept to you guys.

**21 Character Tweet TEST:**

[image: Short Tweet]

**140 Character Tweet TEST:**

[image: Long Tweet]

Here is the code I'm using (note that the "lowerleft" div is styled by an external CSS):

```
<div id="lowerleft">
  <div id="twitterbutton" style="z-index:100;padding-left:50px;padding-top:75px">
    <div class="tri"style="width:160px;"id=”twitter_update_list”>
      <div id="twitter_div">Latest Tweet:</div>
        <br />
        This is a test. TEST.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**If I didn't explain myself exactly, let me try one last time:**

> Is there anyway to set an anchor in css to make sure my div doesn't grow vertically towards the negative on the y-axis but for it to expand vertically up in the positive y-axis direction?

Comment: You can absolutely position it and give it a `bottom` anchor point. How exactly you apply absolute positioning depends on your structure, but it shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: Hmm... okay will try to figure that out. Anytime I type css and anchor in google it just gives me info on anchor tags, so I didn't even know this was possible/existed until you just mentioned it. Thanks for the ray of hope!

Comment: Got it! I was using top the whole time. Using bottom does exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks BoltClock♦!

Comment: Glad it worked! Do you want me to post an answer, or would you like to do that yourself?

Comment: If you post it, I can give you the upvote and check as the answer. So... go ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely position it and give it a `bottom` anchor point. This way, as you add content to it it'll expand upwards instead of downwards.

How exactly you apply absolute positioning depends on your structure, but it shouldn't be difficult.